# How do I loop through entries for a specific entry type?

Tags: entry-type, loop, forloop

I would like to loop through entries in a channel but only the ones for a specific entry type. Is this Possible?

I'm using the free version of craft on a test site, I have used the channel for my pages but also want to set up a blog. I have set up a blogPost entry type, is there a way to target this in a loop?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('pages').type('blogPost') %}

{% for entry in entries %}
   {{ entry.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Is what I have cobbled together... any pointers on improvements would be welcome.

Comment: That's exactly how to do it!

Comment: Cheers Brad much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Updating for Craft3 and calling for different types, I wanted to share how I use the entry types to create different header/slider entry.

```
{% set slides = craft.entries().section('slider') %}
{% set entries = slides.all() %}
{% for entry in entries %}
    {% if entry.type == 'type1' %}
        {# Your content for 'type1' Entry here #}
    {% endif %}
    {% if entry.type == 'type2' %}
        {# Your content for 'type2' Entry here #}
    {% endif %}
    {% if entry.type == 'type3' %}
        {# Your content for 'type3' Entry here #}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```